# Azure Datalake Gen1 Permission Denied while iterating over folders

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to iterate over all the folders in Azure datalake Gen1 using Python SDK. I am using a service principal with an owner role assigned to it. However, when I try to access some of the folders, I get a permission denied error. I am not sure if I require any other roles as well because the owner has the highest privilege I guess.

Below is the code which I am using

```
 %pip install azure-mgmt-resource
%pip install azure-mgmt-datalake-store
%pip install azure-datalake-store


  import re
  import datetime;
  from azure.datalake.store import lib, core
  from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
  from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
  from pyspark.sql.functions import udf,split, explode,col,when,concat,array_contains,lit
  import datetime;


  def authenticate(clientId, secretId, tenantId):

      RESOURCE = 'https://datalake.azure.net/'

      tenant = tenantId

      client_id = clientId

      client_secret = secretId

      adlCreds = lib.auth(tenant_id=tenant,

                          client_secret=client_secret,

                          client_id=client_id,

                          resource=RESOURCE)

      adl = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlCreds, store_name="xxx")

      return adl



  clientId = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "datalakesecurity", key = "datalakeclientid")

  secretId = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "datalakesecurity", key = "datalakecredential")

  tenantId = 'xxxxx'

  adl = authenticate(clientId, secretId, tenantId)

  path_to_look= '/'

  level1 = adl.ls(path_to_look)

  print(level1)
```

Comment: Hi @Ash3060, Can you share the code that you have tried?

Comment: @Venkatesan I have updated the sample code to iterate. for example in path to look when I am giving specific path it is failing. I want full access over datalake for my service principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Datalake Gen1 Permission Denied while iterating over folders.

In Azure Data Lake Gen1, the "**Owner**" role has full access to the entire Data Lake account, including all folders and files. Even if you hold the **Owner** role, there are some folder-level permissions that may still bar you from accessing particular folders. You may also give your service principal a **Contributor** position.

> According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-access-control#permissions) Along with the owner role you need to explicitly give the permission to read, write, execute on a folder level.

[image]

[image]

Even if have owner role on your service principle but you don't have the above permissions you will face the permission denied error.